# MAC OS X + stage.fullScreenSourceRect + renderMode set to GPU = wrong mouse position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

When setting stage.fullScreenSourceRect, stage.displayState to StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE; and renderMode to GPU, mouse position is read incorrectly. This is not only for mouseX and mouseY position, but also all the mouse interactions with Sprites, Buttons etc are not working correctly.

Anybody know a solution for this issue?

I have reported a bug at [bugbase.adobe.com](http://bugbase.adobe.com), but there is no response yet.

bug id: [3486120](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3486120)

There is simple sample project attached there. If you also have this problem and you don't know any workaround, please at least vote for the bug.

Thanks.
Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug. I guess you could get around it by scaling and positioning the content yourself when going fullscreen. This may affect performance in comparison with setting the `fullScreenSourceRect`, but at least it should work.

An example (use in your document class):

```
protected var fakeFullScreenSourceRect:Rectangle;

public function Main() {
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(30, 30, 400, 200);
    this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleResize);
}

protected function handleResize(e:Event):void {
    if (this.stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN || this.stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) {
        if (this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect) {
            this.scaleX = this.stage.stageWidth / this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect.width;
            this.scaleY = this.stage.stageHeight / this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect.height;
            this.x = -this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect.x * this.scaleX;
            this.y = -this.fakeFullScreenSourceRect.y * this.scaleY;
        }
    } else {
        this.x = this.y = 0;
        this.scaleX = this.scaleY = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried this kind of solutions, but since performance dropped significantly, this solution is not satisfactory. The "native" resize would be much better, and it is when on Windows. Once again, thanks for your help.